# No sound with HDMI on an Acer Aspire Revo 3700

Tags: 11.10, sound, hdmi, aspire

new to ubuntu 11.10 just installed on acer aspire revo 3700.

I dont get any sound through the hdmi cable.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to configure the HDMI output in your sound preferences, left click the **Cog** in the top right corner then select **System Settings** then select the **Sound** option.

You will need to select your HDMI output on the ***Hardware*** tab,

[image: Sound options - hardware]

And ***Output*** tabs

[image]

Then close the dialog box and it should be working. I have to do this each time I use the HDMI output on my laptop - you will need to change back to the internal audio output if you use speakers from the audio out plug.